# A single client to run games from different clients

Tags: steam, origin, ubisoft-connect, epic-games-launcher

I use windows 10 and for gaming I have to use a lot of clients like Steam, Origin, Epic, etc. Is there any way of centralizing these clients? For example one common client instead of all of these or some apps to help?

Answer (score 1):

There are some custom clients that try to solve this problem, for example this one:

https://www.steamgriddb.com/manager (I'm not affiliated with it and not using it):

> Currently Supported Launchers:
>
> Origin
> Uplay
> Epic Games Launcher
> Blizzard Battle.net
> GOG.com

It doesn't allow you to actually buy games, but you can browse and launch them from single place.

**Disclaimer**: it's up to you to decide if you trust such services enough to install them / provide your credentials / grant file system permissions, see [Malware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malware).